# How can I use field validation in my Vue wizard form?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, joi

In an  [example of a Vue wizard form](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2018/01/29/a-multi-step-form-in-vuejs) I tried to add form validation with Joi. How do I set this up logically? The goal is to controll the fields before moving to the second and last page with the `next()` method. Because of the simplicity of this wizard form, I don't want to change to VueFormWizard. To increase the code I erased a lot of fields etc..

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="errorMessage" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      {{errorMessage}}
    </div>
    <form>
      <div v-if="step ===1 ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input v-model="example.title"
                 type="text"
                 class="form-control"
                 id="title" />
         </div>
      <button @click.prevent="next()">Next step</button>
      </div>
      <div v-if="step === 2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="userName">Email.</label>
          <input v-model="example.userName"
                 type="email"
                 class="form-control"
                 id="userName" />         
         </div>       
        <button @click.prevent="prev()">Go back</button>
        <button @click.prevent="createExample" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Joi from 'joi'

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  title: Joi.string().alphanum().min(2).max(40).required(),  
  userName: Joi.string().email(),
  })

export default {
  data: () => ({
    step: 1,
    errorMessage: false,
    example: {
      title: '',
      userName: ''
    }
  }),
  watch: {
    example: {
      handler () {
        this.errorMessage = ''
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    prev () {
      this.step--
    },
    next () {
      this.step++
      if (this.validUser()) {
           return false
      }
    },
    createExample () {
     // Post request
    },
    validUser () {
      const result = Joi.validate(this.huismap, schema)     
  return true
 if (result.error.message.includes('title')) {
    this.errorMessage = 'Vul een titel in van min 2 karakters'
    return false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of browser validation if you set it up like this:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitMyForm">
    <input v-model="form.title" required minlength="4" maxlength="20" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now your browser will prevent you from submitting the form if `title` is empty, if the length is less than 4 or greater than 20.

This solution can do a lot of stuff, even regex checking:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression

However this is limited to a small set of checks and is not supported by older browsers. If you need very specific validation you'd have to use a custom solution, which is described here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html.

Comment: Yes I understand. But is your solution not only validating the end of the form at submit? In my wizard form with 2 pages I would like a field validation with leaving page 1 and going to page 2

Comment: you are free to use multiple `<form>` :) . You only send the data when you want to, using the method you create.

Comment: thanks for inspiring me! From a pragmatic point of view I decided to split my validation error messages. now it s working